# Pytorch RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (128) must match the size of tensor b (134) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on a CycleGAN implementation. With this implementation, I tried converting images to LAB color space. The Tanh function at the final layer of the generator and discriminator was causing issues with the conversion, so I added a correction below. However, when I call my generator(which has the correction on the final layer), I get an error message. Here is the generator code

```
class TanhCorrection(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, steepness=4):
        super(TanhCorrection, self).__init__()
        self.lumi_offset = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([1.]))
        self.steepness = steepness

    def steep_sig(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + torch.exp(-self.steepness * x))

    def forward(self, x) -> torch.Tensor:
        x_l = x[:, 0:1, :, :]
        x_ab = x[:, 1:, :, :]
        x_l = (B_L - A_L) * (x_l + 1) / 2 + A_L
        x_ab = (B_AB - A_AB) * (x_ab + 1) / 2 + A_AB
        return torch.cat((x_l * self.steep_sig(self.lumi_offset), x_ab), dim=1)

class GlobalGenerator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_nc, output_nc, ngf=64, n_downsampling=3, n_blocks=9, norm_layer=nn.BatchNorm2d,
                 padding_type='reflect'):
        assert (n_blocks >= 0)
        super(GlobalGenerator, self).__init__()
        model = [nn.ReflectionPad2d(3), nn.Conv2d(input_nc, ngf, kernel_size=7, padding=0), norm_layer(ngf), nn.ReLU()]
        # downsample
        for i in range(n_downsampling):
            mult = 2 ** i
            model += [nn.Conv2d(ngf * mult, ngf * mult * 2, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
                      norm_layer(ngf * mult * 2), nn.ReLU()]

        # resnet blocks
        mult = 2 ** n_downsampling
        for i in range(n_blocks):
            model += [ResnetBlock(ngf * mult, padding_type=padding_type, activation=nn.GELU(), norm_layer=norm_layer)]

        # upsample
        for i in range(n_downsampling):
            mult = 2 ** (n_downsampling - i)
            model += [nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * mult, int(ngf * mult / 2), kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1,
                                         output_padding=1),
                      norm_layer(int(ngf * mult / 2)), nn.ELU()]
        model += [nn.ReflectionPad2d(3), nn.Conv2d(ngf, output_nc, kernel_size=7, padding=0), nn.Tanh()]
        model += [TanhCorrection()]
        self.model = nn.Sequential(*model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)


class LocalEnhancer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_nc, output_nc, ngf=32, n_downsample_global=3, n_blocks_global=9,
                 n_local_enhancers=1, n_blocks_local=3, norm_layer=nn.BatchNorm2d, padding_type='reflect'):
        super(LocalEnhancer, self).__init__()
        self.n_local_enhancers = n_local_enhancers

        # global generator model ##
        ngf_global = ngf * (2 ** n_local_enhancers)
        model_global = GlobalGenerator(input_nc, output_nc, ngf_global, n_downsample_global, n_blocks_global,
                                       norm_layer).model
        model_global = [model_global[i] for i in
                        range(len(model_global) - 3)]  # get rid of final convolution layers
        self.model = nn.Sequential(*model_global)

        # local enhancer layers ##
        for n in range(1, n_local_enhancers + 1):
            # downsample
            ngf_global = ngf * (2 ** (n_local_enhancers - n))
            model_downsample = [nn.ReflectionPad2d(3), nn.Conv2d(input_nc, ngf_global, kernel_size=7, padding=0),
                                norm_layer(ngf_global), nn.ReLU(True),
                                nn.Conv2d(ngf_global, ngf_global * 2, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
                                norm_layer(ngf_global * 2), nn.ReLU(True)]
            # residual blocks
            model_upsample = []
            for i in range(n_blocks_local):
                model_upsample += [ResnetBlock(ngf_global * 2, padding_type=padding_type, norm_layer=norm_layer)]

            # upsample
            model_upsample += [
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf_global * 2, ngf_global, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),
                norm_layer(ngf_global), nn.ELU()]

            # final convolution
            if n == n_local_enhancers:
                model_upsample += [nn.ReflectionPad2d(3), nn.Conv2d(ngf, output_nc, kernel_size=7, padding=0),
                                   nn.Tanh()]

            setattr(self, 'model' + str(n) + '_1', nn.Sequential(*model_downsample))
            setattr(self, 'model' + str(n) + '_2', nn.Sequential(*model_upsample))

        self.downsample = nn.AvgPool2d(3, stride=2, padding=(1, 1), count_include_pad=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        # create input pyramid
        input_downsampled = [x]
        for i in range(self.n_local_enhancers):
            input_downsampled.append(self.downsample(input_downsampled[-1]))

        # output at coarest level
        output_prev = self.model(input_downsampled[-1])
        # build up one layer at a time
        for n_local_enhancers in range(1, self.n_local_enhancers + 1):
            model_downsample = getattr(self, 'model' + str(n_local_enhancers) + '_1')
            model_upsample = getattr(self, 'model' + str(n_local_enhancers) + '_2')
            input_i = input_downsampled[self.n_local_enhancers - n_local_enhancers]
            output_prev = model_upsample(model_downsample(input_i) + output_prev)
        return output_prev
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\phill\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\hd\train.py", line 125, in <module>
    train()
  File "C:\Users\phill\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\hd\train.py", line 74, in train
    fake_a = gen_ba(real_b)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\phill\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\phill\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\phill\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\hd\models.py", line 162, in forward
    output_prev = model_upsample(model_downsample(input_i) + output_prev)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (128) must match the size of tensor b (134) at non-singleton dimension 3

Process finished with exit code 1
```